# Background image is not showing right on button

Tags: xml, android-studio, kotlin

I am making an UI on Android Studio.

I want to make a button with background image that I made.

Then I want to write some text on it.

However, when I set the background on button, it is just showing me black color.

I eidted theme.xml file to change status bar's color to black.

---

This is the background that I want to apply on button.

[image: OriginalButtonBackground]

This picture showing that background image is not applied as I intended.
[image: Main ui screen]

This is theme.xml file which I edited to change status bar's color.
[image: theme.xml]

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for this kind of issue!

it is because of Material components in theme.xml.

all you need to add to fix this is:

```
<style name="btn_style" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@null</item>
</style>
```

Write this code in your theme.xml.
Then reference it to your button.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced such before.
Change Button to appCompatButton